# iphone app cant be started on device after being killed - works fine on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios4, multitasking

I want to put an update to my App and I'm encountering heavy issues. When sent to background and being brought back to foreground, the App works fine. However, after killing the process from multitasking (running in the background), the App tries to resume from the point where it left AND it freezes, which means, I cant start the App anymore!!!! I have made no changes to the code, except updating my OS from 4.0 to 4.0.1.

Can anyone help me out on this?

A weird thing is: I cannot reproduce this problem on the simulator, it works just fine there.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution. Apple states in the updates: 'When debugging your multitasking enabled app, avoid manually pausing and continuing from the debugger when the application is suspended in the background. Pausing an application that is suspended in the background disrupts proper multitasking behavior until the application is relaunched.' So I tested it on a device for distribution and it seems to work fine, so all you have to do is ignore the debugger - it seems. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

My app works fine for me in Debug mode (I'd advice against working with Distribution mode cause of all the hassle of provisioning profile, iTunes sync... and also you can't see the console message in real time).

The reason you can't do anything after killing the app and relaunching it is most likely because you run it directly from XCode (Command + Enter) and the app is still "running". Just click to the Red button to stop the debugging, then you can relaunch the app from the SpringBoard normally. Or just Command + Enter to rebuild it again.